Converting a VARCHAR to an INT; is TRY_CAST or TRY/CATCH better?
I'm looking at some T-SQL code (in a SQL Server 2019 environment) where a parameter in a stored procedure is an "overloaded" VARCHAR (15) parameter, and later is meant to be converted to an INT.  I pondered how this could go wrong -- it may not actually be a numeric string, or it might represent a number too big to fit in an INT variable.  I want something efficient, and I began pondering using a TRY_CAST instead of just CAST, or using a TRY/CATCH block, to do the conversion on success, or allow "a way out" if not.  To simplify...
-- given these...
declare @AParamter varchar (15) = '214748364700'; -- 100x bigger than max INT
declare @AVariable int;

-- ...approach 1...
set @AVariable = try_cast( @AParamter as int );

if (@AVariable is null) begin
    print 'ERROR: invalid parameter';
end

-- ...approach 2...
begin try
    set @AVariable = cast( @AParamter as int );
end try
begin catch
    print 'ERROR: invalid parameter';
end catch

Both work, but I'm wondering which is more "efficient", i.e. requires less resources (and admittedly, either is probably somewhat minimal compared to everything else going on), or if either of these has any hidden "gotchas".
I'm using the sys.dm_exec_*_stats views to gather metrics for the stored procedure I'm testing, and I'm assuming the Total_Worker_Time and Total_Elapsed_Time metrics are the most relevant, but they can vary so much (within the context of the proc) that it's hard to see which approach may be having a bigger (or any) effect, for better or for worse.  So, I'm asking this mostly out of curiosity as to which approach is a better practice, or what else might be even better yet.
I tried to search the web and StackOverflow for any info, but I couldn't seem to find any results referring to performance in comparison.
Note: my preference would be to not overload this parameter; me personal feeling is that it should be multiple parameters, each of the correct type, and only one of them not null at a time, with specific checks to assure that we have one and only one filled in, but...  that's not really up to me.

try_cast should be preferable. If anything, it's less code, also, try catch has some sideeffects when it comes to transactions etc

I would not be concerned with performance validating the scalar parameter. The cost will be microseconds of processor time, too small to accurately measure.

I think I had it in my head that TRY_CAST was using .NET; when I looked into that again, I realized that it's TRY_PARSE which does that, so yeah, with that in mind, I would assume TRY_CAST has less overhead.
As to scalar performance, you're correct that with one call, who cares, but I'm working in an environment that is having a lot of procs called a lot of times, and CPU is always a concern, so I'm thinking more along the lines of making sure I'm not using a pattern that may contribute to a snowballing of stuff.  It is the last concern, but the thing I was most curious about that day.

TRY_CAST is far and away faster, as well as being much clearer.
The following script will show you that:
declare @v varchar(10) = 'hello';

declare @i int = 1;
declare @x int;
declare @dt datetime2 = sysdatetime();
while @i < 10000
begin
    set @x = try_cast(@v as int);
    set @i += 1;
end;
select datediff(mcs, @dt, sysdatetime());


set @i = 1;
set @dt = sysdatetime();

while @i < 10000
begin
    begin try
        set @x = cast(@v as int);
    end try
    begin catch
    end catch;
    set @i += 1;
end;
select datediff(mcs, @dt, sysdatetime());

db<>fiddle
10k loops takes about 1 second if you are catching, whereas TRY_CAST takes around 30ms.
The reason is probably simple: BEGIN CATCH involves a lot of gubbins with exception handling, such as walking the stack and unwinding. Whereas TRY_CAST can just return a null.

Doesn't make much difference https://dbfiddle.uk/TxmRfvWA

Nope https://dbfiddle.uk/_Bcfik1Y 625212mcs against 1578080mcs so still twice as fast

I deleted my answer and critical comments. Although there are repeatable cases where TRY/CATCH was faster this is 1) not important in one-time-actions and 2)  might depend on other influences.
